# Proper headers to prevent spoofing, but allow custom replies

Tags: smtp, sendmail

Our application sends e-mail alerts to lists of users. We want the users to be able to have discussions about these e-mails, but we don't want, ever, to get a copy of the discussions back to our application. Here's an example:

```
Us: Send notice
Them: Hits reply-all button, sends e-mail to their associates, but not us
...
```

In a "normal" world, we'd just have an address that goes into a bit bucket, like "noreply@example.com", but nooooo, that's not good enough (because the reply e-mail leaves the client's network for parts "unknown").

Our first attempt at this was to change the "From:" address to something that use chooses, from *inside* their network, e.g.

```
"joe@client.example.org"
```

and this often works, but runs afoul of Ironport's anti-spoofing rules. I can't say that I blame them, but I wish there was a way to say, "It's okay, see, we're the good guys."

What can we do that doesn't involve a custom rule in Ironport?

What would a custom rule look like? (We don't have Ironport, we just have to work with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use schemes deployed by mailing lists?

header sender (`From:` header in message): joe@client.example.org
envelope sender (`MAIL FROM:` in SMTP session): owner-joe@client.example.org

Bounce email should go to `owner-joe@client.example.org`, user replies should go to `joe@client.example.org`